# Getting error in oracle 11g

Tags: sql, oracle, select, oracle11g

Error:

> ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected NUMBER got CHAR

SQL:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN 
(
SELECT COUNT(COMP_CODE) FROM COMPANY_MASTER
)=0 THEN 1
ELSE 
(
SELECT LPAD((SELECT MAX(COMP_CODE)+1 FROM COMPANY_MASTER),3, 0) NOS FROM DUAL
)
END AS DOCNO FROM DUAL;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both branches of the if-else should return the same type. If the `else` branch returns a string (which is the return value of `lpad`), so should the `if` branch. E.g.:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN 
(
SELECT COUNT(COMP_CODE) FROM COMPANY_MASTER
)=0 THEN '1' -- '1' is a string literal
ELSE 
(
SELECT LPAD((SELECT MAX(COMP_CODE)+1 FROM COMPANY_MASTER),3, 0) NOS FROM DUAL
)
END AS DOCNO FROM DUAL;
```